# Is there a compiler warning for casting double pointer to single pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Consider the following code which is a simplified version of something I did IRL (and have done a couple of times) where there is an "extra" address-of operator which should not be there.

```
#define HEAD \
    int type

struct my_struct {
    HEAD;
};

struct my_struct_extended {
    HEAD;
    int a;
    int b;
};

int my_function(const struct my_struct *data) {
    return data->type;
}

struct my_struct_extended global = { 2, 3, 4 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    struct my_struct_extended *local = &global;

    //        ADDRESS-OF SHOULD NOT BE HERE \/
    return my_function((struct my_struct *) &local);
}
```

There are to structs, one base struct and one extended struct. An instance of the extended struct is casted to the base struct to be used in `my_function()`. Due to the misplaced address-of operator however, the function basically starts working on trash data.

The compiler (in my case GCC) always warns when you pass a double pointer to a function expecting single pointer, but when a struct needs to be casted, such an error is masked. I guess the compiler interprets the cast as **"YES! I REALLY WANT THIS"** or something.

Is there a warning which can be enabled to trap this?

Note: The real-world case is with casts involving `struct sockaddr`:

```
ret = rrr_ip_send (
    &err,
    ip_data->ip_udp.fd,
// EXTRA ADDRESS-OF    \/
    (struct sockaddr *) &addr,
    addr_len,
    (void *) send_data,
    send_size
);
```

Comment: As soon as you cast, you promise not to shoot yourself in the foot.  Seems you didn't want that foot :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan True, fortunately I have a spare foot on the other leg.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the IRL code. If you've done this more than once, you need to consider a change in your coding style.

Comment: There are compiler warnings when you have a type mismatch without a cast. But a cast is interpreted as meaning you really want to do it.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know which casts are intentional and which it should warn about?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know!

Comment: @user3386109 I added the actual function call in the example. And maybe your're right, there were three calls in the same function doing that. I guessed it happened after a rewrite where `addr` previously was inside a struct and the `&` was correct.

Comment: This might be something a good IDE will catch.

Comment: I hope most would agree that the design of `struct sockaddr` and friends was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is no warning for casting between different pointer-to-struct types, as the presence of an explicit cast is seen as an instruction to the compiler that you know what you are doing and do not want to see any warning.

Despite this, the compiler still has warning options for potential misalignment and overflow when casting.

A good practice to avoid this mistake is to never use a cast unless absolutely necessary. So using that practice you would have written:

```
return my_function(&local);
```

and then gotten the compiler diagnostic about a type mismatch in arguments to `my_function`.

Comment: That is true, but in this case it is correct to pass in both struct types into the function, so the cast must actually be there to avoid warning about incompatible types. The warning which I then again want to trap this other error....  I guess Mr. Stroustrup would have had something to say about this :)

Answer (score 0):

This hand coding of inheritance in C in not uncommon but you do need to be very careful and define your functions to strictly take the inherited type pointer or the base type pointer depending on where it sits in your hierarchy.  Unfortunately the typo with the address operator in your example is just a bug that can hide in these designs because of the casts.
One way to mitigate this a little bit is to do all your casts as separate line expressions with the appropriate comment like:

```
#define HEAD \
    int type

struct my_base_struct {
    HEAD;
};

struct my_derived_struct {
    struct my_base_struct base;
    int a;
    int b;
};

int my_base_function(const struct my_base_struct *self) {
    return self->type;
}

struct my_derived_struct global = (struct my_derived_struct){ .base.type = 2 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    struct my_derived_struct *local_derived = &global;
    // get base pointer
    struct my_base_struct *base = (my_base_struct *)local_derived;

    return my_base_function(base);
}
```

This alerts others to the trickery that is being attempted.

BTW: The overloading of the sockaddr struct is a notorious source of confusion.